# How can I change accounts when I am trying to open up a Google Survey

Tags: google-forms, google-account, google-surveys

In my web browser I'm logged into multiple Google accounts

Usually, when using a Google product I can change my account:

1. By adding/editing `/u/<account_position>/` in the URL, where `<account_position>` is usually 0, 1, 2 or 3.

   E.g. https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/1/
2. by adding/editing the `GET` parameter `authuser`.

   E.g. https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/?authuser=2

However, I can't find how to do it for [Google Surveys](https://surveys.google.com/) and they don't even allow me to select the account through the user interface.

**So... how can I change the Google account I'm using when accessing Google Surveys?**

Answer (score 0):

```
https://surveys.google.com/warm-welcome?authuser=2
```

```
https://surveys.google.com/your-surveys?authuser=1
```

This pattern works for me.
Make sure you do the same even after the page is redirected